# Pass in environment variables to OpenTelemetryCollector config

Tags: open-telemetry

I have installed an OT Operator for Kubernetes, I now need to create an OT collector instance to start collecting and reporting metrics.
The example on the page is super simple

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: simplest
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:

    exporters:
      logging:

    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [logging]
```

However my config has a bit more to it and requires an api key which I would like to pass in as an env variable.
Is there anyway to do that?

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: simplest
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:

    exporters:
      logging:
      otlp:
        endpoint: $ENDPOINT
        headers:
          api-key: $API_KEY

    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [logging]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `${env:ENV_VARIABLE}` to read the environment variable.
Details are available here. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#environment-variables